# Multiple line in or RCA sound inputs

Tags: audio-recording, sound-cards, audio-adapters

I basically want to setup my Linux computer to record multiple Line ins.

The problem is I have only one line in input in my sound card.

I need multiple Line in or RCA audio inputs. I'm looking for either PCI devices or USB or bluetooth or any other cheap solution.

Reason: I have many so called 12 volt CCTV mics. They take 12v input and output RCA audio. I used a RCA to 3.5 mm converter and connected one to the Line in of my computer and that worked perfectly.

Comment: Found cheap cables like these http://www.amazon.com/HDE-Audio-Video-Camcorder-Adapter/dp/B003QA5LA0/ . But I'm not sure if they work with PC.

Comment: ^^^ They are not really RCA to USB converters. They have no circuits built-in. They are for connecting some proprietary cameras to PCs.